# Unable to Sign in with Apple Supabase for native app

Tags: ios, swift, supabase

I'm try to implement SignInWithApple for a native app through Supabase using the [gotrue-swift](https://%20https://github.com/supabase-community/gotrue-swift?tab=readme-ov-file) SDK.

I used the code from the example so this ought to be straightforward. I've configured signin with Apple capability. I've also enabled the provider in my supabase dashboard.
Trying to SignIn, but I'm getting this error:

```
   GoTrue.GoTrueError.api
  ▿ api: GoTrue.GoTrueError.APIError
    - message: nil
    ▿ msg: Optional("Provider (issuer \"https://appleid.apple.com\") is not enabled")
      - some: "Provider (issuer \"https://appleid.apple.com\") is not enabled"
    ▿ code: Optional(400)
      - some: 400
    - error: nil
    - errorDescription: nil
```

Here the main code:

```
      ...
      SignInWithAppleButton { request in
                  let nonce = randomString()
                  self.nonce = nonce
                  request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
                  request.requestedScopes = [.email, .fullName]
                } onCompletion: { result in
                  Task {
                    do {
                      guard let credential = try result.get().credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential
                      else {
                        return
                      }

                      guard let idToken = credential.identityToken
                        .flatMap({ String(data: $0, encoding: .utf8) })
                      else {
                        return
                      }

                        try await accountProvider.userAcccount.gtClient.signInWithIdToken(
                        credentials: .init(
                          provider: .apple,
                          idToken: idToken,
                          nonce: nonce
                        )
                      )
                    } catch {
                      dump(error)
                    }
                  }
                }
```

I've checked my AppleId settings and I see that my App is enabled to use SigninWithApple. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled sign in with apple inside the supabase auth dashboard